# Function arguments destroyed after map::count is called

Tags: c++, string, lua

I have a weird issue, I'm not sure where it is coming from. I pass two strings from lua back to c++. The first string is a file name which has to be converted to a wchar_t* due to this being what DirectX requires for the built in texture loading functions. The second string stays the same (being a normal char*). I used breakpoints and found that after this "TextureList.count(filepath)" is ran, the 2 strings which are passed to the function seem to get destroyed and become random garbage. Normally this function works fine if I type the strings in myself but for my script engine I need to be able to load textures externally using lua.

```
short ID = lua_tonumber(env, 1);
string Texture = lua_tostring(env, 2);
const char* Archive = lua_tostring(env, 3);

wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;

wstring final_ = convert.from_bytes(Texture);

for (auto& Sprites : StageBackground->BackgroundSprites)
{
    if (Sprites->Object_ID == ID)
    {
        LoadTextureFromMemory(final_.c_str(),Archive, Sprites->Texture);
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the function that is called from lua to load textures.

EDIT: I noticed that the problem can be narrowed down to the "Archive" variable being the one that is destroyed. I still cannot find out why. If I switch from Release to Debug mode in Visual Studio I get debug assertion errors.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the strings were already destroyed but just happened to still contain valid data because that portion of the stack hadn't been used yet. If you need to keep the strings around, make your own copies of them whose lifetime you control.

Comment: How would I make an independent copy?

Comment: I can't tell you because your question is too vague. For example, which variable is it that seems to be destroyed? `convert`? `final_`? `Archive`?

Comment: final_ and Archive are the ones passed into LoadTextureFromMemory and those are the ones that are destroyed.

Comment: Actually, I tried typing out those two strings into variables but those have the same errors as the ones from lua. I don't know what's going on with my program.